# How to set current index of or move backwards though an rxjs observable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I'm using an rxjs observable to model a sequence of steps that occurs in my app.

Pseudocode

```
const steps = [{id: "step1"}, {id: "step2"}, {id: "step3"}]

//... then at some point later do things based on the steps
from(steps).pipe(
    concatMap((step) => {
        ... do stuff with each step, perhaps including needing to go back to previous step
    })
)
```

Given this pattern how might I model "going back" if some condition makes it necessary?

For example going from step1 -> step2 -> step3 -> step2 -> step3

From what I can tell rxjs seems to be pretty strictly one-way-linear. I haven't found a way to set the position/index of an observable (if that's the right way to conceptualize it).

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious but it seems like this could be a fairly common use case for observables created from arrays.

Comment: Given that Observables are streams of events that happen at certain points in time, it might be difficult to go back ;-) Guess we'd need to travel faster than light speed

Comment: You can perhaps "save" steps in some kind of a list.

Comment: Basically you can't know whether the stream came from an array of some other source. You could always use the `repeat` operator to resubscribe to the source. If it's cold, like in your case, you will get all the notifications again. If it's hot, you'd need to use something like `shareReplay` to replay the past events.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this but I'm unsure if this is the "correct" pattern.

I created a subject and had it emit values into itself to control which item from my sequence came next. Looks like this:

```
const steps = [{id: "step1"}, {id: "step2"}, {id: "step3"}, {id: "step4"}]

const runMySequence = async () => {

    let currentStep = steps[0]
    const sub = new Subject<typeof steps[number]>()

    sub.pipe(
         tap((step) => currentStep = step),
         concatMap(....process the step, do all sorts of stuff),
         tap((step) => {
             //Here's where we decide which step to execute next
             const idx = steps.indexOf(currentStep)
             if (idx !== steps.length - 1) {
                //Based on whatever condition we could decide to "go back" to a previous step here if we wanted
                sub.next(steps[idx + 1])
             } else {
                 //All out of steps, complete the subject
                 sub.complete()
             }
          })).subscribe()

    //kick off the sequence
    sub.next(steps[0])

    //and wait for it to finish
    await sub.toPromise()

}
```

This seems like a fairly clean way to achieve this. Any thoughts on why this pattern might have issues or better ways to do it?